# Прописная в названии лозунга

Tags: прописная-строчная

Теперь средства массовой информации ведут кампанию, лозунг которой "Чем больше, тем лучше".

Будет ли неправильным писать название лозунга со строчной?

Answer (score 3):

*Правило*

1. Нераспространенная   прямая речь может являться членом предложения.
2. Прямая речь заключается в кавычки, но двоеточие перед ней не ставится.
3. Допускается использование как прописной, так и строчной буквы в начале прямой речи.

*Примеры*

Он вскочил, но она воскликнула «сидите, играйте!» и опять исчезла. Вдруг раздалось громкое «Ура!»

*Решение*

Здесь возможны оба варианта, но в случае строчной  буквы прямая часть будет выделена в меньшей степени, поэтому лучше оставить прописную букву.

Comment: правила ясны, но где здесь прямая речь?

Comment: Прямая речь - это дословная передача  высказывания.   Содержание высказывания можно предать и другими способами (бессоюзное сложное предложение со значением изъяснения; сложноподчиненное предложение с придаточным изъяснительным – так называемая косвенная речь; представление слов автора в виде вводного предложения). Кроме того, возможны упрощённые варианты оформления прямой речи (только с кавычками, без двоеточия или прописной буквы), например: Теперь средства массовой информации ведут кампанию, лозунг которой "Чем больше, тем лучше".

Comment: Весь вопрос в том, насколько этот лозунг официален. Немножко изменим предложение. 


Теперь средства массовой информации ведут кампанию, лозунг которой "пишу как хочу". Здесь тоже надо с большой буквы?

Comment: Вы, наверное, хотите сказать, насколько это вообще реальный лозунг. Вариант "...лозунг которой "пишу как хочу" - это образное употребление слова, поэтому здесь надо писать строчную букву, то есть использовать упрощенную форму прямой речи с минимальной выделительной способностью

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, строчная здесь больше подходит. Это не официально сформулированный лозунг, и уж тем более не прямая речь, а придуманное автором самостоятельно определение.

Comment: Дело не в официальности лозунга. Переходя от классического оформления прямой речи к упрощенному оформлению (сначала убрали двоеточие, потом убрали прописную букву), мы последовательно уменьшаем ее выделительное свойство. И здесь автор должен решать, какой вариант ему больше подходит. Прописная буква свидетельствует о том, что мы собираемся логически подчеркнуть содержание лозунга, а при строчной букве оно нам менее интересно.